# Redirect with .htacess - URL with regex to URL

Tags: regex, redirection, htaccess

I have a temporary need to redirect some installer files on my web site. The redirects that are working now look something like this:

```
Redirect 302 /installer_1.0.0.zip http://www.example.com/download/installer_1.0.3.zip
Redirect 302 /installer_1.0.1.zip http://www.example.com/download/installer_1.0.3.zip
Redirect 302 /installer_1.0.2.zip http://www.example.com/download/installer_1.0.3.zip
```

I would like to use a regex instead of having multiple lines for each version I need to redirect. I have tried these options with no success:

```
Redirect 302 /installer_(.*).zip http://www.example.com/download/installer_1.0.3.zip
Redirect 302 /installer_([0-9+]\.[0-9+]\.[0-9+]).zip http://www.example.com/download/installer_1.0.3.zip
```

**EDIT**

I've tried  what Joni Salmi has recommended and cannot get it to work. I've tried several iterations of similar rules I've encountered on the web, all to no avail. I feel like I'm missing a fundamental concept here. My `.htaccess` file on the root of this site has several rules and redirects and they all seem to work just fine. But none is like this, where I have a regex in the middle of an URL string.

Hopefully I can get some more answers from those who have d one this kind of thing in their own projects.

Comment: You do know that a 301 redirect means it is permanent and will be cached by browsers, proxies and robots? If this is meant to be temporary, you should use a 302 instead.

Comment: Yes, @user2313067 good point. I grabbed this from another permanent redirect... I will consider which redirect to use when finally implementing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !installer_1\.0\.3\.zip 
RewriteRule ^/installer_(.*).zip$ http://www.example.com/download/installer_1.0.3.zip [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think this might work but it's causing loop...

Comment: Please, go ahead and try the edited version. It should stop the loop. You can try the condition without backslashes if that doesn't work.